# How can I write a Windows application without using WinMain?

Tags: c, winapi, program-entry-point, crt, winmain

Windows GUI applications written in C/C++ have 'WinMain' as an entry point (rather than 'main'). My understanding of this is that the compiler generates a 'main' function to be called by the C Runtime. This 'main' function sets up the necessary environment for the GUI and calls into 'WinMain' (specifying the instance handles etc.).

In short, I believe console and GUI application startup to differ in the following way:

Console application:
C Runtime --> 'main' function (hand-coded)

GUI application:
C Runtime --> 'main' function (compiler-generated) --> 'WinMain' function (hand-coded)

I would like to both validate this understanding and find out how I can hand-code a Windows GUI with just a 'main' function (i.e. without having to write 'WinMain').

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have an incorrect understanding.  The difference between main and WinMain, apart from some differet initialization code, is the parameters passed to it.

main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

While WinMain looks like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
);
```

Something has to setup those parameters and make the call, and that's the startup code.  When you compile and link a program, one of the linker parameters is the entry point, and that will be, depending on a console or GUI app, a different bit of startup code.

You can certainly write your own startup code, just go into your visual c++ source directory and you can find the startup code, it's called crt0.c and it's in the VC\crt\src directory.

Answer (score 8):

With Just main, you can not code Winmain. For justifications, Following statements were taken from 
 http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/03/6644060.aspx

> [In Windows Programming,] Why wasn't the application entry point called
>   main? Well, for one thing, the name main was already taken, and
>   Windows didn't have the authority to reserve an alternate definition.
>   There was no C language standardization committee back then; C was
>   what Dennis said it was, and it was hardly guaranteed that Dennis
>   would take any special steps to preserve Windows source code
>   compatibility in any future version of the C language. Since K&R
>   didn't specify that implementations could extend the acceptable forms
>   of the main function, it was entirely possible that there was a legal
>   C compiler that rejected programs that declared main incorrectly. The
>   current C language standard explicitly permits implementation-specific
>   alternate definitions for main, but requiring all compilers to support
>   this new Windows-specific version in order to compile Windows programs
>   would gratuitously restrict the set of compilers you could use for
>   writing Windows programs.
>
> If you managed to overcome that obstacle, you'd have the problem that
>   the Windows version of main would have to be something like this:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[], HINSTANCE hinst,
>          HINSTANCE hinstPrev, int nCmdShow);
> ```
>
> Due to the way C linkage was performed, all variations of a function had to agree on the
>   parameters they had in common. This means that the Windows version
>   would have to add its parameters onto the end of the longest existing
>   version of main, and then you'd have to cross your fingers and hope
>   that the C language never added another alternate version of main. If
>   you went this route, your crossed fingers failed you, because it turns
>   out that a third parameter was added to main some time later, and it
>   conflicted with your Windows-friendly version.
>
> Suppose you managed to convince Dennis not to allow that
>   three-parameter version of main. You still have to come up with those
>   first two parameters, which means that every program's startup code
>   needs to contain a command line parser. Back in the 16-bit days,
>   people scrimped to save every byte. Telling them, "Oh, and all your
>   programs are going to be 2KB bigger" probably wouldn't make you a lot
>   of friends. I mean, that's four sectors of I/O off a floppy disk!
>
> But probably the reason why the Windows entry point was given a
>   different name is to emphasize that it's a different execution
>   environment. If it were called main, people would take C programs
>   designed for a console environment, throw them into their Windows
>   compiler, and then run them, with disastrous results.

Hope this clears your doubts.

Answer (score 6):

It works the other way. There's a statically linked object file which comes with the compiler that holds the actual entry point. That entry point does initialization and then calls your entry point (i.e. WinMain).

What that static part expects to call may be tweakable. For example, in Visual Studio there's a field for the entry point name in the linker settings.

Comment: So what is the order of execution in the console and GUI application cases? Is the static part different in those two cases? Where does the C runtime fit in?

Comment: First the static part is executed, then it calls the user-implemented entry point. It can be different or it can be the same, but the linker could link the call to different entry points depending on settings. You can think of this static part as it is part of the C runtime.