# How to create a cross platform window handler?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, macos, cross-platform

I might not be searching for the correct terms, but I'll try to explain what I am looking for (probably common).

In Windows to create a window you usually go through [`WinMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but not all platforms (Linux, OS X, etc) use this function as an entry point to the program.

While I know there are a lot of libraries out there, I'm more curious about the implementation for educational reasons and not looking for a 3rd party library to handle this for me.

The implementation of this is huge I'm sure, but I'm curious on a more abstract level, how would you write your entry point to be able to handle window creation on multiple platforms.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, particularly that one as it is *way more complicated* than you can imagine. Just use a portable windowing library (Qt, GTK, wxwidgets...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - I'm interested in how it works, not how to implement it.

Comment: ... and if you're interested in the implementation, read one of those existing implementations to start with

Comment: Typically a toolkit has a bunch of classes that represent windows, edit boxes, etc. and standard methods on them.  Then they have a separate implementation for every platform of all the low-level bits of each of these classes.  Creating such a toolkit is a huge job.

Comment: @arx - I'm not interested in a toolkit, I'm interested in getting a blank window up to attach a DirectX or OpenGL context to.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: glut could be an option there... it is a toolkit, but somehow of a light one, and is cross platform. If your interest is just creating an OpenGL window for drawing in a multi platform way, you should really ask that, instead of the more vague and complex question you are asking here.

Comment: @afuzzyllama "a separate implementation for every platform of all the low-level bits".  There's no magic.  Write windowing code for every platform you want to support or use a toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm curious on a more abstract level, how would you write your entry point to be able to handle window creation on multiple platforms.

The entry point of a C++ program is `main`, and that is cross platform. After that, you will need to use the specific library you need to create the windows and anything else. Different platforms/libraries can provide a `main` function for you that will perform the initialization and then call a specific function (`WinMain` in the case of windows)

You might want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564576/how-can-i-write-a-windows-application-without-using-winmain) regarding WinMain.

Comment: After looking over that question, it makes a lot more sense.  Thanks for clearing it up!